# Give a name to an array of JSON objects : into php

Tags: php, json

here i get the JSON Array from MYSQL by PHP as String how can Give name to the Array JSON object to be Like this .

```
{
    "task":
        [
            {
                "tid":"1",
                "titls":"testing",
                "uid":"1101",
                "subject":"test",
                "sp":"10",
                "date":"2018-01-01"
            },
            {
                "tid":"2",
                "titls":"tesssting",
                "uid":"1101",
                "subject":"tesssst",
                "sp":"11",
                "date":"2018-01-01"
            }
        ]
}
```

and this the php file how can give the Array JSON object .

```
// an array to save the application data
$rows = array();

// iterate to query result and add every rows into array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $row; 
}

// close the database connection
mysqli_close($con);

// echo the application data in json format
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: give a name to the array? It's already called `$rows`, and you could easily have chosen another name if you don't like that one. I feel I must be misunderstanding your question...

Comment: @RobinZigmond  i know `$rows` but the JOSN result become without name like that ` [
     {
     "tid":"1",
     "titls":"testing",
     "uid":"1101",
     "subject":"test",
     "sp":"10",
     "date":"2018-01-01"
      },
      {
     "tid":"2",
     "titls":"tesssting",
     "uid":"1101",
     "subject":"tesssst",
     "sp":"11",
     "date":"2018-01-01"
    }
   ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i try this code and it's work good for me and this what i want

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
// echo the application data in json format
echo json_encode(array('task' => $rows), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a *name* to your JSON string, you could try doing the following:

```
// an array to save the application data
$rows = array();

// iterate to query result and add every rows into array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $rows[] = $row; 
}

// close the database connection
mysqli_close($con);

// echo the application data in json format
echo json_encode(array("task" => $rows));
```

I would also suggest that you use `header('Content-Type: application/json');` to specify that you are replying with JSON data if you have plans to use this in an application.